# How to pass the number of total users to simulate and spawn rate in the locust script itself

Tags: locust

How do I pass the number of total users to simulate and spawn rate in the Web UI when I run the locust file, instead, I would like to pass them as variables in the script itself?

```
class QuickstartUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 2.5)
    users = 10
    spawn_rate = 1

@task
    def on_start(self):
        filenumber="ABC"

        # Get file info
        response = self.client.get(f"/files/" + filenumber)
        json_var = response.json()
        print("response Json: ", json_var)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably do it by accessing the Runner in code, but it would be much easier if you used a [Load Shape](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/generating-custom-load-shape.html).

```
class MyCustomShape(LoadTestShape):
    time_limit = 600
    spawn_rate = 20

    def tick(self):
        run_time = self.get_run_time()

        if run_time < self.time_limit:
            # User count rounded to nearest hundred.
            user_count = round(run_time, -2)
            return (user_count, spawn_rate)

        return None
```

`tick` is called automatically, you just have to return a tuple of the user count and spawn rate you want. You can do whatever work you want to calculate what the users and rate should be. There are [more examples in the GitHub repo](https://github.com/locustio/locust/tree/master/examples/custom_shape).

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you Solowalker!